# Topological groups and compact elements

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, reference-request, abelian-groups, topological-groups

I would like to ask for references about *compact elements* of topological groups. For the record, an element $g$ of a topological group is *compact* if $g$ lies in a compact subgroup.

I specifically would like to study the proof for the following results:

**Proposition 1.** *The set of compact elements forms a compact subgroup*.

**Proposition 2.** *Considering $G$ a locally compact, connected and abelian group. The set of compact elements are dense in $G$*

I don't know precisely if that is the hypothesis we need for these results.

Thank you.

Comment: Proposition 2 must require additional (or other) hypotheses, since the reals under addition form a locally compact, connected, and abelian topological group whose only compact element is 0.

Comment: Proposition 1 is obviously false, even for discrete groups. Proposition 2 is obviously false as well. What examples of noncompact abelian connected groups do you know?

Comment: Which hypothesis should I add to make the proposition 1 be true? I'm studying Lie groups and the specific problem is proving that $K_0 = \hbox{cl}\{\exp{tX_s}: t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a compact subgroup of $G$, a semisimple group with finite center. Also, $X_s$ is a semisimple element from the algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, which means that to a complexification of $\mathfrak{g}$, $ad(X_s)$ is similar to a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Proposition 1 is not true even in the case of abelian groups. Although in an abelian group the set of compact elements forms a subgroup, but this subgroup is not necessarily compact. Proposition 2 is very strange. Besides $\mathbb{R}$, consider the multiplicative group $\mathbb{C}^*$. Find the compact elements in this latter group.

Comment: Guys, these are not real propositions, it is just the subject I'm looking for. I'm trying to access the available books with this specific content. Some of the articles I found are not available for free. Books are easier to find and study with.